# Esper: How to fix error java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in core Esper engine?

Tags: java, esper

When using Esper, I obtained this error.

What could be the cause?

```
2017-02-05 15:51:59,781 [...] ERROR com.espertech.esper.core.service.ExceptionHandlingService  - Exception encountered processing statement '...' statement text 'INSERT INTO Window
    SELECT *
    FROM TableWithJoins
    WHERE test=3
    ORDER BY (Math.abs(Total)) DESC
    LIMIT 10' : null
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.ArrayDeque$DeqIterator.next(ArrayDeque.java:643)
            at com.espertech.esper.event.EventBeanUtility.flatten(EventBeanUtility.java:186)
            at com.espertech.esper.collection.FlushedEventBuffer.getAndFlush(FlushedEventBuffer.java:41)
            at com.espertech.esper.view.internal.SingleStreamDispatchView.execute(SingleStreamDispatchView.java:56)
            at com.espertech.esper.core.context.util.EPStatementAgentInstanceHandle.internalDispatch(EPStatementAgentInstanceHandle.java:127)
            at com.espertech.esper.epl.named.NamedWindowServiceImpl.processHandle(NamedWindowServiceImpl.java:468)
            at com.espertech.esper.epl.named.NamedWindowServiceImpl.processDispatches(NamedWindowServiceImpl.java:247)
            at com.espertech.esper.epl.named.NamedWindowServiceImpl.dispatch(NamedWindowServiceImpl.java:214)
            at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processThreadWorkQueueFront(EPRuntimeImpl.java:858)
            at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processThreadWorkQueue(EPRuntimeImpl.java:810)
            at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processWrappedEvent(EPRuntimeImpl.java:500)
            at com.espertech.esper.event.EventSenderBean.sendEvent(EventSenderBean.java:84)
```

I am using `Esper v5.2`.

Comment: Note: This question is officially tagged as "Share your knowledge, Q&A style". Please take this into account if you are considering downvoting.

Comment: Current version is 6.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by a join in a previous `insert` statement.

To fix, add `undirectional` to one of the join statements.

The reason this works is that if there is a join statement in Esper, any incoming event from any of the join clauses can trigger an update. By adding "unidirectional", this means that only one thread pushes events downstream, rather than two, which solves any threading issues.

This issue may have been fixed in later versions of Esper.

Comment: Note: This question is officially tagged as "Share your knowledge, Q&A style". Please take this into account if you are considering downvoting.